# How to update one recycler view content from another recycler view item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm new to Android world, and stuck with one issue now. I tried a lot from past 3-4 days, but still couldn't fix the issue. With lots of hope I'm posting this question today here. Looking forward to hear from you.

In same activity, I've two recycler views. One at top (adapter name SubCategoryAdapterTop) and one at below full screen (adapter name SubCategoryAdapter). I'm passing one position (POS) to SubCategoryAdapterTop captured from previous main activity, and passing two positions to SubCategoryAdapter (POS, POS1 -default 1). May be if you look at my codes below, can understand it properly. Now I wish to click on each item on top recycler view and acoordingly want to pass the clicked position as POS1 to SubCategoryAdapter and regenerate/refresh the content of it. Example- if I click 2nd item in top recycler view, then POS1 should be 2 and passed on to SubCategoryAdapter along with earlier POS value and refresh it's content accordingly.

Please help me how to do that. Thanks in advance !

[Activity with 2 recycler views:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Qfa.jpg)

SubCategoryAdapter Code:

```
public class SubCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapter.MainViewHolder> {
    List<response_model_fetch_subcategory> data;
    Context context;

    public SubCategoryAdapter(List<response_model_fetch_subcategory> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubCategoryAdapter.MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subcategory_single, parent, false);
        return new MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubCategoryAdapter.MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.subCategoryTextView1.setText(data.get(position).getPname());
        holder.subCategoryTextView2.setText(data.get(position).getPbrand());
        holder.subCategoryTextView3.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(position).getPquantity1()));
        holder.subCategoryTextView4.setText(data.get(position).getPunit());
        holder.subCategoryTextView5.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.valueOf(data.get(position).getPcost1())));
        holder.subCategoryTextView6.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.valueOf(data.get(position).getPcost1())));
        holder.subCategoryTextView7.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(position).getDiscountamount()));
        Glide.with(holder.subCategoryImageView1.getContext()).load("http://10.0.2.2/localshop/localshopimages/product/"+data.get(position).getPimage1()).into(holder.subCategoryImageView1);

        holder.subCardViewContainer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginVerifyOTP.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView subCardViewContainer1;
        ImageView subCategoryImageView1;
        TextView subCategoryTextView1, subCategoryTextView2, subCategoryTextView3, subCategoryTextView4, subCategoryTextView5, subCategoryTextView6, subCategoryTextView7;
        Button subCategoryButton1;

        public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            subCardViewContainer1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCardViewContainer1);
            subCategoryImageView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryImageView1);
            subCategoryButton1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryButton1);
            subCategoryTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView1);
            subCategoryTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView2);
            subCategoryTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView3);
            subCategoryTextView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView4);
            subCategoryTextView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView5);
            subCategoryTextView6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView6);
            subCategoryTextView7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextView7);
        }
    }
}
```

SubCategoryAdapterTop Code:

```
public class SubCategoryAdapterTop extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapterTop.MainViewHolder> {
    List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop> data1;
    Context context;
    int row_index = 0;


    public SubCategoryAdapterTop(List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop> data1, Context context) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubCategoryAdapterTop.MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subcategory_topsingle, parent, false);
        return new SubCategoryAdapterTop.MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubCategoryAdapterTop.MainViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        holder.subCategoryTextViewTop1.setText(data1.get(position).getSubcategoryname());
        holder.subCardViewContainerTop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (row_index == position) {
            holder.subCardViewContainerTop1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_item_bg);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.subCardViewContainerTop1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_item_bg);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data1.size();
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayoutCompat subCardViewContainerTop1;
        TextView subCategoryTextViewTop1;


        public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            subCardViewContainerTop1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCardViewContainerTop1);
            subCategoryTextViewTop1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryTextViewTop1);
        }
    }
}
```

SubCategoryActivity Code:

```
public class SubCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView subRecyclerView, subRecyclerViewTop1;
    SubCategoryAdapter adapter;
    SubCategoryAdapterTop adapterTop;
    String pos, pos1;
    Intent intent;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_category);

        // recycler view code
        subRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.subRecyclerView);
        subRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        subRecyclerViewTop1 = findViewById(R.id.subRecyclerViewTop1);
        subRecyclerViewTop1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        intent = getIntent();
        pos = intent.getStringExtra("pos");
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for incoming intent extras: " + pos);
        pos1 = Integer.toString(1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for incoming intent extras1: " + pos1);

        fetchingProduct(pos, pos1);
        fetchingProductTop(pos);

    }

    public void fetchingProduct(String pos, String pos1) {

        Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> call = apicontroller
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .getSubCategoryData(pos, pos1);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> call, @NonNull Response<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        List<response_model_fetch_subcategory> data = response.body();
                        adapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
                        subRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Last_Error" + t.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for incoming intent extras_: " + pos);
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for incoming intent extras_1: " + pos1);

    }


    private void fetchingProductTop(String pos) {
        Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>> call = apicontroller
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .getSubCategoryNames(pos);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>> call, @NonNull Response<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop> data1 = response.body();
                        adapterTop = new SubCategoryAdapterTop(data1, getApplicationContext());
                        subRecyclerViewTop1.setAdapter(adapterTop);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Last_Error" + t.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

apiset coode:

```
public interface apiset {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login_user.php")
    Call<response_model_login_user> getRegister(
            @Field("mobilenumber") String mobilenumber,
            @Field("area") String area,
            @Field("firstname") String firstname,
            @Field("lastname") String lastname,
            @Field("emailid") String emailid,
            @Field("deliveryaddress") String deliveryaddress
    );


    @GET("fetch_category.php")
    Call<List<response_model_fetch_category>> getData();

    /*
    @GET("fetch_subcategory.php")
    Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> getSubCategoryData();
    */

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("fetch_subcategory.php")
    Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategory>> getSubCategoryData(
            @Field("pos") String pos,
            @Field("pos1") String pos1
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("fetch_subcategory_names.php")
    Call<List<response_model_fetch_subcategoryTop>> getSubCategoryNames(
            @Field("pos") String pos
    );
}
```

activity_sub_category.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubCategoryActivity"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">


 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/subFrameLayoutTop1"
     android:background="@color/gray_light"
     >

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/subRecyclerViewTop1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

         />

 </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/subFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/subRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="@integer/material_motion_duration_short_1"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to implement nested recycler view concept, but it's not working.